# Why the vlookup function does not work

Tags: vlookup

[image]

I worked on some projects, but cannot figure out why this kind of vlookup function does not work. I even tried a very simple example, and it didn't work.

Comment: Please click "Just an example" to see the screenshot. Thanks~

Answer (score 0):

From https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1 "The value you want to look up must be in the first column of the range of cells you specify in table-array".

Your example is trying to search the second column.  Swap column 1 and 2 and the lookup should work.